# Django Admin Login Allauth Workaround

Tags: django-admin, django-allauth

Django-Allauth does not limit login attempts to the Django admin login page. Luckily Allauth provides a workaround for this.

But as I am a beginner, I cannot figure out in what Django file to put the code. And do I need to put it in more files than one?

https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/common/admin.html

It says:
"An easy workaround for this is to require users to login before going to the Django admin site’s login page:"

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

admin.site.login = staff_member_required(
    admin.site.login, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL
)
```

It is also noted that: "It would need to be applied to every instance of AdminSite."

How can I make it work? Where should I place this code?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be added whereever you import the AdminSite:

> An easy workaround for this is to require users to login before going to the Django admin site’s login page (note that the following would need to be applied to every instance of AdminSite)

In my case, I imported the admin-URLs in the "main"-urls.py file of my project, like this:

```
    path(
    'admin/', 
    admin.site.urls
    ),
```

So I've just added this above:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.conf import settings 

admin.site.login = staff_member_required(
    admin.site.login, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL
)
```

Which leads to this urls.py-File:

```
admin.site.login = staff_member_required(
admin.site.login, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL
)
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'admin/', 
        admin.site.urls
        ),
]
```